# My take on something vs my understanding of something

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

What’s the difference between understanding and take?

For example, consider the following two questions:

- what’s your take on this issue?
- What’s your understanding of this issue?
  Would it make a subtle difference if one were to substitute one with another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A person's **take** on something is that person's opinion about that thing, usually on a subject that is clearly a matter of opinion.

> My take on Woody Allen is that his humor depends on self-put-downs .

A person's **understanding** of something (in a simian construction) is a statement of fact, or at least of alleged fact.

> My understanding is that Omicron is more infectious than Delta.

The word "understanding" can also be used in quote a few other ways, of course.

> - I thought that you and I had an understanding.
> - At that time his understanding of English was quite limited.

However "take" is significantly more in formal and casual than "opinion". It is also a bit vaguer, and someone's take on something could include both an opinion and supporting beliefs about the facts on that issue, particularly when the facts are not known with certainty.

Comment: It seems like a take is closer to an opinion than an understanding. So is there any difference between what’s your opinion on it and what’s your take on it?

Comment: @Ray I would say that "take" is more informal, and also is vaguer, and can include elements of both opinion and understanding, although usually mostly opinion.